# can't move minute hand on ontouch method of surfaceview

Tags: android

I have tried many ways to do this.....and i'm able to move the minute hand on ontouch of view but the problem is that it can move even when I do not touch it.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

    float x = e.getX();
    float y = e.getY();

 switch (e.getAction()) {
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     //find an approximate angle between them.
     Log.i("test", "value x is"+x);
     Log.i("test", "value y is"+y);
     /*float dx = x-cx;
     float dy = y-cy;*/
     getRotationAngle(x,y);
     float dx = x-cx;
     float dy = y-cy;
     double a=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
     Log.i("test",":: "+Math.toDegrees(a));
     this.degree = Math.toDegrees(a);
     this.invalidate();
 }
 return true;
 } protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

 super .onDraw(canvas);
 boolean changed = true;

 int availableWidth = getRight() - getLeft();
 int availableHeight = getBottom() - getTop();

 int x = availableWidth / 2;
 int y = availableHeight / 2;
 cx = x;
 cy = y;
 final Drawable dial = mDial;

 int w = dial.getIntrinsicWidth() + 100;
 int h = dial.getIntrinsicHeight() + 100;

 boolean scaled = false;

 if (availableWidth < w || availableHeight < h) {
     scaled = true;

     float scale = Math.min((float) availableWidth / (float) w, (float) availableHeight / (float) h);

     canvas.save();
     canvas.scale(scale, scale, x, y);
 }

 if (changed)
 {
     dial.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
 }

 dial.draw(canvas);

 canvas.save();
 float hour = 4 / 12.0f * 360.0f;

 canvas.rotate((float) degree, x, y);

 final Drawable hourHand = HourHand;

 if (changed) {

     w = hourHand.getIntrinsicWidth() + 30;
     h = hourHand.getIntrinsicHeight() + 30;

     hourHand.setBounds(x - (w / 2), y - (h / 2), x + (w / 2), y  + (h / 2));
 }

 hourHand.draw(canvas);
 canvas.restore();

 canvas.save();
 float minute = Minutes / 60.0f * 360.0f;

 /*if (bearing == 0)
 {
     canvas.rotate(minute, x, y);
 }
 else
 {
     canvas.rotate((float)bearing, x, y);
 }*/

 final Drawable minuteHand = MinuteHand;

 if (changed) {

     w = minuteHand.getIntrinsicWidth() + 30;
     h = minuteHand.getIntrinsicHeight() + 30;

     minuteHand.setBounds(x - w, y - h, x + w, y  + h);
 }

 minuteHand.draw(canvas);
 canvas.restore();

 if (scaled) {
     canvas.restore();
 }
```

}

while I am touching anywhere in the view, my clockhand starts rotating when it should not. Any help there?